# EF 7 Beta 8 -> EF7 RC1 - No longer can create migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

After attempting to change my existing project from beta 8 to RC1 I get the following after running `dnx ef migrations add Init`

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqliteDesignTimeServices, EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design'.
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices (System.String provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build (Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration (System.String name, System.String outputDir, System.String contextType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+Executor+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<AddMigration>b__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+Executor.Execute (System.Action action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqliteDesignTimeServices, EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design'.
```

My `project.json` file contains along with others the following

```
"dependencies": {
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
},
"commands": {
  "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},
```

What do I need to do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

Package names are case-sensitive on Linux and OS X due to the case-sensitive filesystem. Make sure to use `EntityFramework.Sqlite` not `EntityFramework.SQLite` in your **project.json** file. (See GitHub Issue [dotnet/cli#236](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/236))

Comment: Thanks. I can get this to work by adding in EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design to my dependencies but simply fixing the case did not work. I've create a stripped down example in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ChristopherHackett/dd414fa5acf24d9b9255)

Comment: Yeah. Dnx is broken on this. It may require (1) rename case, (2) delete ~/.dnx/packages and (3) delete project.lock.json. :-/

Answer (score 0):

First resolve your references / dependencies. All reference warnings must be solved and must be "7.0.0-rc1-final".

If there is no "7.0.0-rc1-final" version then probably something  is renamed to a different name. See the [annoncement repro](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) for breaking changes

```
"dependencies": {
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
},
```

Comment: All dependencies are now at rc1-final and I have no dependencies warnings after ``dnu restore``

Comment: Oke yout project.json list show rc1 and not rc1-final. Which version of the dnx are you using to run ef command `dnx --version`

Comment: Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16202
 Type:         Mono
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Darwin
 OS Version:   10.10
 Runtime Id:   osx.10.10-x64

Comment: dnx looks ok. If you start a new asp.net-5 web application and change sqlServer by sqllite. and remove migration folder. Do you get errors when using `dnx ef migrations add Init` On my machine this works fine